# Kendo grid copy cells (datasource original values) to paste external

Tags: kendo-grid

I am able to copy the displayed cell's data to clip board. But how to copy the original data source values (4.2898) instead of Grid cell values( 4.28). 
Here precision is applied on grid but original value is different in data source

Comment: Please update your question with what you have already tried

Comment: Same thing but it's confusing that the reason i update it

Comment: //events to capture when Ctrl + C is pressed
                    $("#cellSelection").bind('copy', function (e) {
                        var grid = $("#cellSelection").data("kendoGrid");
                        if (grid != null && grid.areaClipBoard != undefined) {
                            console.log("copied content is:");
                            console.log(grid.areaClipBoard.val());
                        }
                    });